# Kernel Module Version magic error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I am trying to load a kernel module through modprobe. I am using yocto project to build the kernel. When I try to load the kernel in my Custom hardware I am getting following errors.

```
modprobe g_serial
    configfs: version magic '3.14.38-6UL_ga+ge4944a5 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8 ' should be '3.14.38-6UL_ga+ge4944a5 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv6 p2v8 '
    modprobe: can't load module configfs (kernel/fs/configfs/configfs.ko): invalid module format
```

below is the dmesg log

```
configfs: version magic '3.14.38-6UL_ga+ge4944a5 SMP preempt mod_unload modversions ARMv7 p2v8 ' should be '3.14.38-6UL_ga+ge4944a5 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv6 p2v8 '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this error when I was doing the kernel module and kernel compilation in two different builds. Now I am doing in the single build and the driver is loading successfully.